# Does R have an add-on to colorize scripts?

Tags: r, colors, colorize

I am new to the R language, but not to the programming world. I have been using excellent code editors such as Notepad++ and Eclipse and, therefore, am used to colored codes.

Is there anything that can be done to colorize the scripts inside R?

I know I can use Notepad++; however, this will require going back and forth between the two software, which is not convenient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [RStudio](http://www.rstudio.org/).

Comment: Thank you very much. I just downloaded and installed it! Are you using RStudio yourself?

Comment: You're welcome. I'm more of a JMP user at the moment, but I have used RStudio in the past. It's pretty nice and actively developed.